# sending USSD in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, ussd

I want to write a simple c# application runs on windows mobile 6 which can send USSD messages

Is there any library that could help me in doing this??

or is there any examples that explains how to use [lineSendUSSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862581.aspx)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to P/Invoke to access the phones TAPI  functions.

Have a look at this thread: [Windows Mobile Developer Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/3194eb16-407e-44b8-bc1a-004e5be43f12)