# How to interact with USSD menu?

Tags: android, mobile, gsm, ussd

I would like to write a program that would interact with an existing USSD service, so I need a way to dial the code, 'navigate' the menus,send additional commands and read any data. What would be a good way to achieve this? 
I am open to any technology/platform at the moment.
I have looked into Android but there doesn't seem to be a USSD Api.
Thankx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's currently it's impossible on Android: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285.

I left a comment that I need this feature and I hope some day Google will add this API.

But it's look like you can do it on winmo: [sending USSD in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725860/sending-ussd-in-c)

Also you can try linux and usb modem - http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Telephony/gsm-ussd-57048.shtml